# How to fill combobox in cxGrid depend on column value in same cxGrid

Tags: sql, combobox, devexpress, tcxgrid

myComboboxDatasetSQLQuery:

```
select 0 as priv_id, 'нет' as priv_name from dual
union all
select 1 as priv_id, 'просмотр' as priv_name from dual
union all
select 2 as priv_id, 'изменение' as priv_name from dual
union all
select 3 as priv_id, 'администратор' as priv_name from dual where :USER_TYPE != 1
```

**Question**:
- How i can pull my lookUpComboBox cell in cxGrid use depend value in USER_TYPE cell in the same cxGrid?

Answer (score 1):

We've published several knowledge base articles showing how this feature can be implemented:

[How to vary the editor's settings in the cells of a Grid column (Table View) or row (Card View)](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/ViewKBIssue.aspx?kbid=K18140)

[How to provide different editors in a Grid column (Table View) or row (Card View)](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/ViewKBIssue.aspx?kbid=K18139)

[How to provide different set of items  within the ImageComboBOx column for different cells](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=AQ15121)